# Eliminate columns with a high percentage of "unknown"

Tags: r

I am cleaning up a data frame and would like find an efficient way to drop columns where a certain percentage of the values are "UNKNOWN"

In order to clean up columns with high percentage of NA, I have successfully used:

```
df<-df[,colSums(is.na(df))/nrow(df)<.95]
```

but I cannot find the equivalent operator for comparing each value of a column to a string

Here is a mock dataframe:

```
name<-c("UNKNOWN","UNKNOWN","UNKNOWN","JOE","UNKNOWN","MARY")
age<-c(35,45,32,46, 24,50)
gender<-c("UNKNOWN","UNKNOWN","F","M","M","F")

df<-data.frame(name,age,gender)

name    age     gender
UNKNOWN 35  UNKNOWN     
UNKNOWN 45  UNKNOWN     
UNKNOWN 32  F       
JOE 46  M       
UNKNOWN 24  M       
MARY    50  F
```

If I chose a threshold of 50%, I would like to drop the column "name"

Thanks in advance

Comment: You should be able to replace the function `is.na(df)` with `df == "UNKNOWN"`

Comment: Try `df[,colSums(df == "UNKNOWN")/nrow(df)<.5]`

Comment: You can also do `df[, colMeans(df == "UNKNOWN") < .5]`

Comment: Thanks all! that worked :)